# Trying to get the average number of a value by day in SQL

Tags: sql, average

I am trying to get the average number of posted jobs by day and cannot figure it out from any of the similar prior questions asked on this site. This seems pretty basic but for some reason it isn't working. Can someone please help? Thank you!

```
select avg(count(*) 
from select (count(*), to_char(thedate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as date 
     from jobs where companyid = 1)
```

Comment: Doesn't this give syntax errors?

Comment: `SELECT AVG(*) FROM jobs WHERE company_id = 1`? Otherwise, please give more info on your requirements and expected output

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Im getting a syntax error with the below query. I am using Postgres. Thank you all for your help so far!

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help was able to figure it out after it was determined that we needed it over the last 90 days and not all time: select avg(a.count) from (select
count(*)
, to_char(expired, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as date
from
jobs
where
companyid = '1'
and expired is not null
and expired > current_timestamp - interval '90 days'
and expired < Now()
group by
expired
order by
expired) as a

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select avg(jobNumber), date
from select (count(*) as jobNumber, to_char(thedate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as date
 from jobs
 where companyid = 1
 Group by to_char(thedate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
) innerSelect
Group by date
```